# How to do case-insensitive multiple replacement using "vi"?

Tags: vi

Basically I want to do the following replacement using vi:

```
Apple->Orange
apple->orange
APPLE->ORANGE
```

Is there any way to do it in one line?

Comment: What if you had aPpLe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed command

```
$ cat os.txt
BEST
UNIX
Unix
uNiX

Sed supports "i" or "I" for "case insensitive" search and replacement
$ sed 's/unix/BEST/i' os.txt
BEST
BEST
BEST
BEST
```

If you need to use vi try this command

```
1,$ s/apple/orange/gI
```

Comment: The OP's question seems to want a case-*preserving* replacement, although with a different length of output string from that of the input string.